# Send HTML code via form

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I'm confused.

I try export a html page with [MPDF](http://mpdf1.com). i see the examples, and how to use it is like this:

```
<?php    
$html = '
<h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
<p>P: Nulla felis erat, imperdiet eu, ullamcorper non, nonummy quis, elit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a eros at ligula vehicula pretium. Maecenas feugiat pede vel risus. Nulla et lectus. </p>';

include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

So, I have to put html code into a variable then mpdf class will generate the pdf file.

I have problem like this:

I want to print a page that generated dinamically with php after a form submit from user. This is a report page. User choose specific time periode they want, the page will show the report.

So, I have to get the generated html code after user submit the form. I'm using `ob_get_contents()` to do this and then send it with a form to the php page that have mpdf script above, say pdf.php.

Here my code at pdf.php:

```
<?php
include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 


$htmlx = "$_POST[htmlx]";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlx);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

the pdf have created, but it is not display correctly like it should (the pdf created not display html page correcly).

i think that maybe the html code generated is wrong and mpdf doesn't understand the html code. so i try like this:

I've tried to copy generated html code and make php page like an example above I show. The pdf generated is display correctly the page!

I don't understand why this could be happend. Maybe i cannot send html code through form in php?

I'm sorry for my bad english. I do hope that you can understand my problem and can solve help me to solve it.
Thank you.

EDIT:

Here my form to send html code:

```
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
$html = str_replace('"','\"',$html);

?>
<form action="pdf.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" value="Print to PDF">
    <textarea name="htmlx" style="display:; width: 100%; height:300px;" readonly><?= $html ?></textarea>
</form>
```

EDIT

this is example of my generated html:

```
<style>
*{
    font-family: arial;
}
body{
    background: #fff;
}
table#myTable{
    border:solid 7px #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    behavior: url(/files/border-radius.htc);
}
#myTable th{
    font: normal 11pt 'century gothic';
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    color:#000
}
#myTable th.header {
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    color:#fff
}
#myTable th.headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(/template/default/images/asc.gif);
    background-color: #eee;
    color:#fff
}
#myTable th.headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(/template/default/images/desc.gif);
    background-color: #eee;
    color:#fff
}
#myTable tr {
    border:solid 1px #3e6189;
}
#myTable td {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    border:solid 1px #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 9pt
}
@media print
  {
  .blabla{
    display:none;
  }
  }
</style>



</head>

<body>
<script>
function printPage() { print(); }
</script>

    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%" id="myTable">
        <tr class="bgTransUng25">
            <th width="5">No</th>
            <th width="70">Pembelian</th>
            <th width="100">Oleh</th>
            <th width="70">Tanggal</th>
            <th width="">Detail Pembelian</th>
            <th width="70">Paket Pengiriman</th>
        </tr>
            <tr class="bgTransWht71" align="center">
            <td align="right">1.</td>
            <td>00122</td>
            <td>Iko Uwais</td>
            <td align="right">2 Jul 2012</td>
            <td>

                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr class="bgTransWht25" align="center">
                        <td align="left">Kaos BW 9500 003</td>
                        <td align="right" width="70">3  pcs</td>
                        <td width="100"><div style="text-align:left">Rp.<div style="float:right; text-align:right">285.000</div></div></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="bgTransWht25" align="center">
                        <td align="left">Kaos BW 9500 003</td>
                        <td align="right" width="70">7  pcs</td>
                        <td width="100"><div style="text-align:left">Rp.<div style="float:right; text-align:right">665.000</div></div></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="bgTransWht25" align="center">
//and so on...
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the user submits the form that has the value for $_POST[htmlx]?

Comment: What exactly is not displayed correctly? The lay-out or the content?

Comment: i have table inside the page and it is not show correctly. I thought that maybe i have to escape double quote or single quote. that's why there is str_replace. but, it's not.

Comment: How do you set the layout for your table, inline or with CSS. Maybe post an example of the HTML for the table (or a part, if it's a large one)?

Comment: i've edit my question.
but i think the problem it's not the html. because, when i make a php file like the example at the first in my question with inside `$html` is the generated html code, it worked. the layout display correctly.

Comment: @TikasMamed, thanks for the HTML code. Please explain what is going wrong in the layout in the PDF? Width of table, cells, nested table, borders, corners....

Comment: i've just try to add image but i'm not allowed to put image since my reputation below ten :D

Comment: Can you post a link to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$html = str_replace('"','\"',$html);
```

with:

```
$html = htmlentities($html);
```

HTML doesn't use backslash for escaping, it uses entity codes.

Comment: thank you. but i've tried that too before i submit this question here and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is...

"display:;"

Just remove that altogether. Display should default to something that will at least show the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `stripslashes()`, worked for me:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML( stripslashes($htmlx) );
```